# How to bind a variable in a defined function?

Tags: scheme, lisp

The context :
I am trying to do something like this (scheme "pseudo-code"):

```
(with-midi-channel 0
    (begin 
        (note-on 60 127)
        (plenty-of-other-midi-commands))
```

With note-on defined like this :

```
(define (note-on note velocity)
    (send-midi-message channel note velocity))
```

In haskell, i would have used a reader monad.
I thought "with-midi-channel" could just be a simple "(let ((channel 0)) ...)", but it looks like it is not so simple.

Here is some equivalent code, to explain the best as i can :

```
(define (test)
    (display a))

(let ((a 1))
   (test))    ;; I get "unbound variable a in (display a)

((let ((a 1))
  test))      ;; same error

((let ((a 1))
   (lambda () (display a)))) ;; it works, but i would like to be able to do the same 
                             ;; with an externally defined function
```

My question is also a pretext to learn how it works under the hood !

By the way, Racket doesn't even accept this definition, whereas other scheme implementations do :

```
(define (test) (display a)) ;; a: unbound identifier in: a
```

I hope my question is formatted correctly, as it is my first post here ^^

Comment: Why isn't `channel` a parameter to `note-on`?

Comment: Scheme uses lexical scoping. Binding `channel` outside of `note-on` won't be visible within it.

Comment: What you're looking for is `fluid-let`, which implements dynamic scoping. It's not part of standard Scheme.

Comment: @Barmar "Why isn't channel a parameter to note-on?" --> good point : i am trying to find a way to not have to pass always the same parameter in a block of code, using standard scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheme (and most recent Lisps) are lexically scoped, so in something like

```
(define (ts)
  (display a))
```

the binding of `a` referred to is the one that was lexically apparent at the time the function was defined (in fact it's a bit more complex than this for top-level definitions, because you want

```
(define (a ...)
  ... (b ...)
  ...)

(define (b ...)
  ...
  (a ...)
  ...)
```

to work).

If there is no such binding this is an error (or, at least, undefined behaviour).

What you want, I think, is dynamically scoped variables.  In Racket (which you seem to be using) you get these via [parameters](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/parameterize.html), and something like this would perhaps work for you:

```
(define current-midi-channel (make-parameter 0))

(define (call/current-midi-channel f c)
  (parameterize ([current-midi-channel c])
    (f)))

(define-syntax-rule (with-current-midi-channel (c) form ...)
  (call/current-midi-channel (thunk form ...) c))

(define (note-on note velocity (channel (current-midi-channel)))
  ;; implementation here but let's just return the channel
  channel)
```

Then

```
> (with-current-midi-channel (12)
    (note-on 1 2))
12
```

It looks like [R7RS](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf) has a similar notion of parameters to Racket (see section 4.2.6) but I am not sure when this arrived in the Scheme standard.

---

I think R7RS was the first Scheme standard which had dynamic binding support like this.  If you're using an implementation which complies to an older standard, or an implementation which complies to no standard at all then either that implementation needs to have its own support for something like this, or, if you are willing to deal with the horrible consequences (thread-safety becomes essentially impossible) you can do something like this:

```
(define current-midi-channel 0)

(define (call/horribly-shallow-binding-current-midi-channel f c)
  (let ([stashed-midi-channel current-midi-channel])
    (dynamic-wind
     (λ () (set! current-midi-channel c))
     f
     (λ () (set! current-midi-channel stashed-midi-channel)))))
```

And now

```
> current-midi-channel
0
> (call/horribly-shallow-binding-current-midi-channel
   (λ () current-midi-channel)
   16)
16
```

If your implementation has `syntax-rules`, then you can abstract this away in a macro for arbitrary variables:

```
(define-syntax with-horribly-shallow-bound-global-variable
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (var val) form ...)
     (let ([stashed-var var])
       (dynamic-wind
        (λ () (set! var val))
        (λ () form ...)
        (λ () (set! var stashed-var)))))))
```

And now

```
> current-midi-channel
0
> (with-horribly-shallow-bound-global-variable (current-midi-channel 4)
    current-midi-channel)
4
```

It should be clear just how nasty and unsafe/limiting this trick is.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer !
actually i am not using racket, but s7. i know it also has fancy features, but i would like to find something using standard scheme. Would it be possible to make a special "define" for midi stuff with a macro, for example ?

Comment: @max22-: if you want fluid / dynamic variables the language really has to provide them.  Fortunately the  most recent Scheme standard (R7RS) does, unfortunately s7 probably is not compliant with that standard.  You can probably do some horrible shallow-binding thing off the back of `dynamic-wind`.

Comment: @max22-: I've added a disgusting hack using `dynamic-wind` which might work on s7 (but is supremely unlikely to be thread-safe).

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested what was your real problem and what were you trying to achieve. But if you were really trying to send multiple messages to object without repeating its name, then you should check [`send*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/ivaraccess.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._send%2A%29%29):

```
(send* edit (begin-edit-sequence)
            (insert "Hello")
            (insert #\newline)
            (end-edit-sequence))
```

is the same as

```
(let ([o edit])
  (send o begin-edit-sequence)
  (send o insert "Hello")
  (send o insert #\newline)
  (send o end-edit-sequence))
```

And if your functions return that object, I would also try [`threading`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/threading/index.html) library and [`~>`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/threading/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._threading%2Fmain..rkt%29._%7E7e%7E3e%29%29) macro:

```
#lang racket

(require threading)

(~> '(1 2 3)
    second
    (* 2))
```

Comment: I am trying to make a custom music live coding tool, and learning scheme at the same time. I would like to avoid making functions with always the same parameters everywhere (channel, velocity, scale, etc).

Comment: @max22- In this case, if you don't want to use macros, you can also try `define`+`set!`. See https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/set_.html and 4.9.1 Guidelines for Using Assignment.